# Write character to div using drop down list java/html/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please excuse my complete lack of knowledge I am very new to all this. I have found some code on here that does kind of what I want so am trying to adapt it. Basically I need to show a character on the screen and then change that character using a drop down list

Heres the HTML

```
<div style = "position: absolute; left: 320; top: 700;" class = "dropdown-menu-     portfolio" >    
 <select id="category-navbar" name="category-navbar" style="width: 131px;">
                    <option value="1">motif 1</option>
                    <option value="2">motif 2</option>
                    <option value="3">motif 3</option>
</select>
```

And the Java script

```
 <script>     
$(".category-navbar value value").click(function() {
// Modifying the label
$('div.dropdown-menu-portfolio label').text($(this).text());

// Removing the class 'select' to the item previously selected
$('option.select').removeClass('select');

// Giving the class 'select' to the item currently selected
$(this).parent().addClass('select');
});

</script>
```

I have been struggling for a couple of weeks with this on and off and really want to get it cracked. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: `$(".category-navbar value value")` what are you trying to select?

Comment: and also, this `class = "dropdown-menu-     portfolio"` should be `class = "dropdown-menu-portfolio"`

Comment: I am trying to select the value in the select form. I have been sitting here and maybe thinking this isn't going to work after all as its dawned on me I need the displayed character in a different place to the elect form if that spossible?

Comment: `$(".category-navbar").change(function(){/*now you can use $(this).val()*/});`

Comment: It doesn't have spaces in my code must be my error when transferring to here Apologies for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but i think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'select#category-navbar', function() {
    $('.selected-value').text($(this).val());
});
```

So when you change an option in the dropdown, it will write the selected option value inside the .selected-value div. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qp2b9Lof/

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code for example with this:

```
$(".category-navbar value value").click(function() {
```

you don't select anything it must be:

```
$("#category-navbar").change(function() {
```

Notice the "#" sign, it selects by ID and second you must use change event

Check JSFiddle for full code
http://jsfiddle.net/qm0msyhf/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class = "dropdown-menu-portfolio" ></div>  
 <select id="category-navbar" name="category-navbar" style="width: 131px;">
                    <option value="1">motif 1</option>
                    <option value="2">motif 2</option>
                    <option value="3">motif 3</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
$("#category-navbar").change(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu-portfolio").html($(this).val());
});
```

click here to see demo - http://jsfiddle.net/1wrt94fc/